# How do I pass data through navigation into a flatlist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I am fetching data from an API that has a JSON file, I am trying to pass the data from app to appstack to sessionsStack that will then bring the data to the home page, currently my console.logs are telling me that my data is only getting to the appStack.

**App**

```
import {AppStack} from '@miniclementine:navigation/AppStack';
import Colors from '@miniclementine:common/appearance/Colors';

const DATA = "https://cg0wsrc3ue.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/getSessions"

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(DATA)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.sessions))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
      console.log("the data: ", data)
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      { isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : <AppStack data={data}/> }
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

**App Stack**

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export const AppStack = ({data}) => {
  console.log("data in appstack", data)
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <MiniClementineTabBar {...props} />}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Sessions" component={SessionsStack} data={data} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Mantras" component={MantraStack} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

**Sessions Stack**

```
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import SessionsHomepage from '@miniclementine:modules/sessions/SessionsHomepage';
import SessionsListPage from '@miniclementine:modules/sessions/SessionsListPage';

export const SESSIONS_HOMEPAGE = 'SESSIONS_HOMEPAGE';
export const SESSIONS_LIST_PAGE = 'SESSIONS_LIST_PAGE';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function SessionsStack({data}) {
  console.log("data in SessionStack", data)
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name={'SESSIONS_HOMEPAGE'} component={SessionsHomepage} data={data} />
      <Stack.Screen name={'SESSIONS_LIST_PAGE'} component={SessionsListPage} data={data} />
      {/* @TODO: The two additional screens you need to create will be defined here */}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**Homepage**

```
import {ClementineIcon, SectionHeader} from '@miniclementine:common/components';
import Colors from '@miniclementine:common/appearance/Colors';

import BlueButton from '@miniclementine:common/components/BlueButton';
import DiscoverMore from '@miniclementine:common/components/DiscoverMore';

export default function SessionHomepage({navigation, data, onPress}) {
  console.log("data in HomePage", data)

  const onPressSectionHeader = ({onPress}) => {
    navigation.navigate('SESSIONS_LIST_PAGE', data)
  };

  const onPressSectionHeaderInvalid = () => {
    alert('Out of scope for this task')
  };

  const Item = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.viewButton} onPress={() => {openSettingsModal(item) }}>
      <Image source={item.image} style={styles.exerciseImage} />
      <View style={styles.detailSection}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
        <ClementineIcon name="button-play" color={Colors.lilac} size={24} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

  const onContactPress = () => {
    Linking.openURL('mailto:alina@clementineapp.co.uk?subject=SendMail&body=Description') 
    // Note: Not supported in iOS simulator, so you must test on a device.
    // If you want to open an email client instead, I would suggest using the library react-native-email-link
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <SectionHeader
            title="Morning Sessions"
            onPress={onPressSectionHeaderInvalid}
            textColor={Colors.Ink}
            textColorSeeAll={Colors.cornflower}
          />
          {/* <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          /> */}
          <DiscoverMore 
            title="Discover more sessions" 
            onPress={onPressSectionHeaderInvalid}
            color={Colors.cornflower}
            textColor={Colors.cornflower}
          />
          <SectionHeader
            title="Pick-me-ups"
            onPress={onPressSectionHeader}
            textColor={Colors.Ink}
            textColorSeeAll={Colors.cornflower}
          />
          <DiscoverMore 
            title="Discover more sessions" 
            onPress={onPressSectionHeader}
            color={Colors.cornflower}
            textColor={Colors.cornflower}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.sleepSection}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../assets/illustrations/sleep_section.png')}
            style={{height: 250, width: '100%'}}
          />
        </View>
        
          <View style={styles.sleepSection}>
            <View style={styles.content}>
              <View style={{paddingVertical: 10}}>
              <SectionHeader
                title="Sleep Sessions"
                onPress={onPressSectionHeaderInvalid}
                backgroundColor={Colors.ink}
                textColor={Colors.stone}
                textColorSeeAll={Colors.mint}
                style={{paddingHorizontal: 10}}
              />
              </View>
              <Text>test</Text>
              <DiscoverMore 
                title="Discover more sessions" 
                onPress={onPressSectionHeaderInvalid}
                color={Colors.mint}
                textColor={Colors.mint}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        <View style={{marginTop: '20%'}}></View>
        <BlueButton title="Leave us feedback" onPress={onContactPress}/>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I am planning to put this data into a Flatlist inside the home page.

Comment: Will this data change after the stack is loaded ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I will not be changing the data, just loading it into a flatlist, and could be styling each item different

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to pass pros in navigation is to use params.
And as your stack is loaded with data you can use the initialParams like below

```
 <Tab.Screen name="Sessions" component={SessionsStack}  initialParams={{data:data}}/>
```

You can access it in SessionsStack like below
export default function SessionsStack({route}) {
.....

```
 <Stack.Screen name={'SESSIONS_HOMEPAGE'} component={SessionsHomepage} initialParams={{data:route.params.data}} />
```

You can do this in the screens which are nested as well.

Warning: this patterns is good only if the data is loaded only once, if you are thinking of changing the data use something like react context.